# Can vsnprintf return negative value of magnitude greater than 1?

Tags: c, c-libraries

Can `vsnprintf()` return a negative value of magnitude greater than 1?  If so, under what circumstances does it do so?

I tried to use `%ls` as format specifier for a char array and also tried to copy larger than what array was allocated. In both cases I am getting -1 as return value.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it can, as in "it is allowed to". The circumstances depend on your platform and are not specified or regulated in any way. The only portable thing to do with the return value is to check it for `< 0` to see if there was an error.

From the standard (7.21.6.12 (3), `vsnprintf`):

> the null-terminated output has been completely written **if and only if the returned value is nonnegative** and less than `n`.

Any given platform may of course make additional guarantees about the return value; consult your documentation.

Comment: Oh, I didn't actually knew it is a C Standard Library function, I was under the (*wrong*) impression that it is Microsoft specific.

Comment: I am using gcc. Will it be possible in gcc ?

Comment: @Knight71: How would I now? Check the glibc sources, this should be easy to locate.

Comment: @Knight71: why are you so interested in the possibility of `vsnprintf()` returning a different negative number? Just checking for a return less than zero is portable, and I'm not sure what would be gained by looking for particular negative numbers.  Note: a buffer that's too small doesn't return an "error", it returns a non-negative number that's greater than or equal to the buffer size (which indicates the output was truncated).

Comment: I was interested in it because of the possibility of bugs for the line                                                               nLen += vsnprintf(&bExpandBuff[nLen], BUFF_LEN - nLen, Msg, arglist);

Answer (score 3):

The C99 standard says:

> #### §7.19.6.12 The `vsnprintf` function
>
> ```
> #include <stdarg.h>
> #include <stdio.h>
> int vsprintf(char *restrict s, size_t n, const char *restrict format, va_list arg);
> ```
>
> #### Description
>
> ¶2 The `vsnprintf` function is equivalent to `snprintf`, with the variable argument list
>   replaced by `arg`, which shall have been initialized by the `va_start` macro (and
>   possibly subsequent `va_arg` calls). The `vsnprintf` function does not invoke the
>   `va_end` macro.<sup>245)</sup> If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is
>   undefined.
>
> #### Returns
>
> ¶3 The `vsnprintf` function returns the number of characters that would have been written
>   had `n` been sufficiently large, not counting the terminating null character, or a negative
>   value if an encoding error occurred. Thus, the null-terminated output has been
>   completely written if and only if the returned value is nonnegative and less than `n`.
>
> <sup>245)</sup> As the functions `vfprintf`, `vfscanf`, `vprintf`, `vscanf`, `vsnprintf`, `vsprintf`, and
>   `vsscanf` invoke the `va_arg` macro, the value of `arg` after the return is indeterminate.

And, since it is defined in terms of `snprintf()`, here's that section:

> #### §7.19.6.5 The `snprintf` function
>
> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
> int snprintf(char *restrict s, size_t n, const char *restrict format, ...);
> ```
>
> #### Description
>
> ¶2 The `snprintf` function is equivalent to `fprintf`, except that the output is written into
>   an array (specified by argument `s`) rather than to a stream. If `n` is zero, nothing is written,
>   and `s` may be a null pointer. Otherwise, output characters beyond the `n`-1st are
>   discarded rather than being written to the array, and a null character is written at the end
>   of the characters actually written into the array. If copying takes place between objects
>   that overlap, the behavior is undefined.
>
> #### Returns
>
> ¶3 The `snprintf` function returns the number of characters that would have been written
>   had `n` been sufficiently large, not counting the terminating null character, or a negative
>   value if an encoding error occurred. Thus, the null-terminated output has been
>   completely written if and only if the returned value is nonnegative and less than `n`.

---

It doesn't say it will return `-1` on an error; just any negative value.  So yes, it is allowed to give a negative value with a magnitude greater than 1 on an error.

---

#### Microsoft's Versions

Note that Microsoft's specification for [`vsnprintf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1kt27hek.aspx) for Visual Studio 2015 says:

> `vsnprintf` returns the number of characters written, not counting the terminating null character. A return value of -1 indicates that an encoding error has occurred. If the buffer size specified by count is not sufficiently large to contain the output specified by format and argptr, the return value of vsnprintf is the number of characters that would be written if count were sufficiently large. If the return value is greater than count - 1, the output has been truncated.
>
> Both `_vsnprintf` and `_vsnwprintf` return the number of characters written if the number of characters to write is less than or equal to count; if the number of characters to write is greater than count, these functions return -1 indicating that output has been truncated. The return value for all functions does not include the terminating null, if one is written.

Note that this was not always the case:

> Beginning with the UCRT in Visual Studio 2015 and Windows 10, `vsnprintf` is no longer identical to `_vsnprintf`. The `vsnprintf` function complies with the C99 standard; `_vnsprintf` is retained for backward compatibility.

For comparison, the Visual Studio 2013 [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1kt27hek%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) says:

> `vsnprintf`, `_vsnprintf`, and `_vsnwprintf` return the number of characters written if the number of characters to write is less than or equal to count; if the number of characters to write is greater than count, these functions return -1 indicating that output has been truncated. The return value does not include the terminating null, if one is written.

The comparable pages for `snprintf()` are:

- [VS 2015](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2ts7cx93.aspx)
- [VS 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2ts7cx93%28v=vs.120%29.aspx)